# Pass pointer to var in C function from Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3

I have a C function in a file with name (Buffer is a C struct)

```
   BufferInit(Buffer *buffer, int32_t size)
```

As I am moving to Swift, in my Swift class I declare a private var like

```
 var buffer:Buffer?
```

and in init function I make a call like this

```
  BufferInit(&buffer, 32)
```

But I get compilation errors, what is the correct way to achieve the same in Swift? I call call the same BufferInit from Objective-C without issues but Swift is messy.

EDIT: Here are details,

```
       typedef struct {
         void             *buffer;
         int32_t           length;
         int32_t           tail;
         int32_t           head;
        } Buffer;
```

Error is compiler is asking me to unwrap buffer and correct the code as(which I don't think is correct):

```
       BufferInit(&buffer!, 32)
```

Comment: Can you add the exact text of the errors you're getting, and the details of the `Buffer` struct?

Comment: My guess: `buffer` should be initialized and not an optional.

Comment: It should be initialized to something, like all values 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C function is imported to Swift as

```
func BufferInit(_ buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Buffer>!, _ size: Int32)
```

and you have to pass the address of a (initialized, nonoptional)
variable of type `Buffer` as an inout expression.
Structures imported from C have a default constructor in Swift which 
initializes all members to zero, so you can write

```
var buffer = Buffer()
BufferInit(&buffer, 32)
```